# Return SharePoint 2013 current user using Javascript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013

I would like to learn how to return a value from one function and use it in another one.
I can show the value in a div or get it in an alert window but I need to use the value in the other function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(testCase,"sp.js");

    function showUserInfo(){
        var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var user = clientContext.get_web().get_currentUser();
        clientContext.load(user);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function(){
            return user.get_loginName();
        },function(sender,args){alert(args.get_message());})
    }


    function testCase() {
      var test = showUserInfo(); 
      alert(test);
    }

</script>
```

Comment: pass the value as a parameter?  It's hard to know exactly what you're asking because I don't see an example of your attempt in your code...  what are you trying to do?

Comment: Yes, pass the value as a parameter. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you need to support Internet Explorer**

To support Internet Explorer, you should use a callback function similar to what @Amos_MSFT suggested. Below you will find my solution, which is quite similar to the solution posted by @Amos_MSFW but with a few differences as well as comments.

```js
// Execute the testCase() function only after sp.js has loaded and is ready.
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function() {
  textCase();
});

function testCase() {
  getLoginName(function(error, success) {
    if (error) {
      alert(error);
    } else {
      /*
       * The line below is not really necessary, as the result of the
       * getLoginName() function is already available in the success
       * variable.  You can already pass it to other functions, like
       * this: alert(success);
       */
      var loginName = success;
      alert(loginName);
    }
  });
}

function getLoginName(callback) {
  var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
  var user = clientContext.get_web().get_currentUser();

  clientContext.load(user);
  clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
    function() {
      /*
       * The first argument of the callback() function is used for the
       * error message, so we need to use null as the first argument
       * when we want to return the login name as the success message.
       */
      callback(null, user.get_loginName());
    },
    function(_sender, args) {
      callback(args.get_message());
    }
  );
}
```

**If you do not need to support Internet Explorer**

I suggest you use a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) if you don’t need to support Internet Explorer. A Promise is a special type of object that represents an operation that is yet to complete, and they make working with asynchronous operations easy and almost fun. I am not fluent enough to explain them in detail, so I advice you to read the article linked above if you are interested. What I will tell you, though, is that we can use a Promise to make sure the `testCase()` function stops and waits for the `showUserInfo()` function to finish, as in waits for the login name to be available.

I have not had the chance to test the code below, but it should work. If not, please let me know. I have also added a few comments in case you are not already familiar with Promises.

```js
const showUserInfo = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    const currentUser = clientContext.get_web().get_currentUser();

    clientContext.load(currentUser);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
      () => {
        /*
         * We resolve the Promise when the query has executed successfully.
         * Resolving a Promise means marking it as fullfilled, or complete, and
         * returning the current user's login name.
         */
        resolve(currentUser.get_loginName());
      },
      (_sender, args) => {
        /*
         * If something goes wrong, we reject the Promise.  Rejecting means
         * marking it as failed, while still returning something.  In this
         * case, we return the error message.
         */
        reject(args.get_message());
      }
    );
  });
}

const testCase = async () => {
  /*
   * We use the await keyword to halt the code and wait for the showUserInfo()
   * function to finish.  What really happens is that we wait for the Promise
   * in the showUserInfo() function to be marked as settled, whether it is
   * fullfilled or rejected, and then assign the result to the test constant.
   */
  const test = await showUserInfo();
  alert(test);
}

SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(testCase, 'sp.js');
```

Comment: Thank you @runar for your comment. Unfortunately I have to make the solution working also in IE. But nevertheless, I appreciate your information about Promise. I learned something new. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have updated my answer now with a solution that works (tested by myself) in Internet Explorer. I hope it works for you as well!

Answer (score 0):

Function executeQueryAsync is asynchronous. You can use the callback function to get the return value.
Sample code for your reference:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function(){
  var testCase=function(callback){                             
        var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var user = clientContext.get_web().get_currentUser();
        clientContext.load(user);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function(){                            
                                callback(null,user.get_loginName()) ;          
        },function(sender,args){alert(args.get_message());})
    }

    testCase(function(error,name){
                if (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return;
  }
  console.log(name);       
                }) 
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you @Amos_MSFT! Your solution didn't solve my problem but I learned there are some synchronous and asynchronous functions.
And using your comment, @runar was able to help me :)